# Fedora lobpcre.so.0

Tags: linux, apache, fedora

I'm getting this error when i try to run apache:

```
./httpd: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

when i do a search for the lib i receive this:

```
/usr/lib/libpcre.so.1
/usr/lib/libpcre.so.1.2.1
/usr/lib/libpcre16.so.0
/usr/lib/libpcre16.so.0.2.1
/usr/lib/libpcre32.so.0
/usr/lib/libpcre32.so.0.0.1
/usr/lib/libpcrecpp.so.0
/usr/lib/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/libpcreposix.so.0
/usr/lib/libpcreposix.so.0.0.2
/usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1
/usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1.2.1
/usr/lib64/libpcre16.so.0
/usr/lib64/libpcre16.so.0.2.1
/usr/lib64/libpcre32.so.0
/usr/lib64/libpcre32.so.0.0.1
/usr/lib64/libpcrecpp.so.0
/usr/lib64/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib64/libpcreposix.so.0
/usr/lib64/libpcreposix.so.0.0.2
```

I tried to upgrade my pcre, to get the so.0 :

```
Package pcre-8.33-11.fc20.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

I'm out of ideas, hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because the version of Apache that is currently installed was built against an older version of pcre.

First upgrade Apache to the latest version in the Fedora repositories. The latest version should have been built against the newer pcre shared object.

If you can't, or won't upgrade Apache, you can downgrade the pcre package to the first version that contains libpcre.so.0, which is 7.8 I think.

If you need a quick fix and aren't using this web server for anything too serious you may be able to make it work by sym-linking libpcre.so.0 to libpcre.so.1.

lastly, you could rebuild Apache manually, which should use the pcre that is currently installed.

Comment: No results :/, tryied to install with ./configure, installed the pcre-devel and nothing.

Comment: While we are trying to figure out exactly why this is occurring you can always symlink libpcre.so.0 to the new version if you need it to work in the interim. Is this a custom Apache install?

Comment: You can probably downgrade pcre to get the older shared object, or try to re-install Apache. The newest Apache from the Fedora repos should have been built with libpcre.so.1.